# Please answer me my husband said divorce 3 times I need to know

Tags: nikah, talaq, husband-wife, husband

my husband divorced me by saying it 3 different time in anger.
He literally lost his mind and out of anger said this.
last year around February he said it Once and around October once and this year January Once, am I divorced now? If he said it out of anger

Comment: We are not a fatwa site. In general if the husband gives divorce then it obviously does count as a divorce. Anger is not a relevant factor.

Answer (score -2):

It depends on level of angriness. if the angriness is so high that the decision is not based on Aql then the divorce is invalid.

Also a divorce is invalid if not witnessed by two just ('adil) witnesses according to the rules of divorce.

> فَاذا بلغنَ اجَلَهُنَّ فَأمسِكوهُنَّ بِمعروفٍ أو فارِقوهُنَّ بِمعروفٍ
> وَأَشْهِدُوا ذَوَى عَدْلٍ مِنْكُمْ وَأَقِيمُوا الشَّهَادَةَ لِلَّهِ
> ذَلِكُمْ يُوعَظُ بِهِ مَنْ كَانَ يُؤْمِنُ بِاللَّهِ وَالْيَوْمِ
> الآخِرِ وَمَنْ يَتَّقِ اللَّهَ يَجْعَلْ لَهُ مَخْرَجاً * وَيَرْزُقْهُ
> مِنْ حَيْثُ لاَ يَحْتَسِبُ
>
> Then when they (the wives) have reached their 'iddah retain them
> honourably, or part from them honourablv. And have two just men from
> among yourselves bear witness, and give testimony for Allah's sake. By
> this then is admonished he who believes in Allah and the Last Day. And
> whoever is careful of (his duty to) Allah, He will provide for him an
> outlet and give him sustenance from whence he never reckoned ....
> [(65:2-3)](https://quran.inoor.ir/en/ayah/65/2/)

[Reference](https://www.al-islam.org/divorce-according-five-schools-islamic-law-muhammad-jawad-mughniyya/divorce)